# Pulley system constraint equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

Question on this page: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/in-the-pulley-system-shown-in-the-figure-the-movable-pulleys-a-b-and-c/

I am confused why the tensions and accelerations in a pully system (with movable pulleys) are related by this formula $\sum T \times a = 0$. I know that given the assumption that the string is inextensible and massless, $\sum l = 0$ for all the segments of the string and thus differentiating it with respect to time, the sum of all accelerations is equal to zero. But where does the T come from (ie how to prove $\sum T \times a = 0$ in general)?

Comment: It's a popular trick that I have only seen in the JEE world, basically,  tension is an internal force since it operates between the pulleys. The work done by them must sum up to zero. $$\sum T.X =0 $$ Further differentiation gives your result.

Answer (score 0):

You might note that if the tensions are all the same, they factor out and you are left with the sum of accelerations.  However, if you assume that the pulleys have mass, then they also have rotational inertia and the tension will change from one segment of string to the next.

Answer (score 0):

First, the answer uses the letter T in two different ways. In the summation, T is the *net* tension-force on a pulley:

$T_c * a_3 + T_b * a_2 + T_a * a_1 = 0$

In the very next line, T is the string tension. This gives the term for pulley C (in the summation) as: T= -2T. They replaced the T in the summation with -2T. Clearly different T’s.

Ok, now for the answer

—————

Moving ONLY pulley C, while keeping the other pulleys at their original heights, will lengthen/shorten the string by twice as much as moving only pulley A, or B.

Start by noting that equation 1 makes sense from the consideration that the string maintains its length (a consideration you alluded to when saying the string length doesn’t change). Changes in the heights of pulleys (and hence accelerations, as you noted) must satisfy 1.

But we started with the summation. Why? The reason that the summation works is because the net tension-force on a pulley is equal to the change in length of the string from moving only that pulley.